# How to undeploy a process with ODE Deployment API?

Tags: bpel, apache-ode, undeploy

I am using the Apache ODE Deployment API to deploy an application. So far so good.

When I try undeploying it I use the following code:

```
private void undeployProcessInODE() {

        DeploymentService service = new DeploymentServiceLocator();

        try {
            DeploymentServicePortType port = service
                    .getDeploymentServiceSOAP11port_http();

            String[] deployedPackages = port.listDeployedPackages();
            String deployedPackage;
            QName[] qNames;
            QName qName;

            for (int i = 0; i < deployedPackages.length; i++) {
                deployedPackage = deployedPackages[i];
                qNames = port.listProcesses(deployedPackage);

                for (int j = 0; j < qNames.length; j++) {
                    qName = qNames[i];
                    port.undeploy(qName);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

and it throws

```
Invocation of operation undeploy failed: org.apache.ode.axis2.OdeFault: Invalid bundle name, only non empty alpha-numerics and _ strings are allowed.
```

because the local part of the `qName` is `bpel258-156` which I guess is some kind of deploy versioning I don't know how to control. My folder inside the `WEB-INF/processes` is `BPEL_process` and all the files inside it `bpel258.bpel` and so on. I can't find a reference to anything where the "version" number is added, so I don't know how to avoid this.

Besides, I'm still not sure what "undeploy" means in ODE terms. Is it just deleting my process folder? What is the .deploy file next to my folder and why is it empty?
I have tried many times to just delete both folder and .deployed but ODE remembers them and tries to locate them. How do I reset this?

As an extra, I must say I ended up changing the whole ode folder from a Tomcat I used through Eclipse to the standalone Jetty in order to have the folder called BPEL_process and overwrite this every time. Before this, ODE would just make a new folder with the versioning number and I didn't know how to change it. Help in this would also be appreciated.

I'm aware these may be too many questions at once but I believe they are all strongly related.